# Returning child type generic to parent type generic in java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I went through a lot of questions related to this and I couldn't clinch my issue.

Here's my question.

I have a parent abstract class.

```
public abstract class Parent{ }
```

I have another two child classes which are extended from the above parent class.

```
public class ChildOne extends Parent{}
public class ChildTwo extends Parent{}
```

In another class, I am using these three classes as bellow.

```
public class A{ 
   public List<ExcelRecord<Parent>> getExcelRecords() {
      ChildOne childone = new ChildOne();
      List<ExcelRecord<ChildOne>> list = new ArrayList<>();

      // some logic here

      return list; // **compilation here**
   }
}
```

The code produces the following compilation error:

```
required: List<ExcelRecord<Parent>>
provided: List<ExcelRecord<ChildOne>>
```

I need to return child type generic to parent type generic. How can I achieve this?

**Note** the return value of this method is being used in the legacy code which **can't** be altered accordingly. It should remain `List<ExcelRecord<Parent>>`.

Answer (score 7):

Use wildcards in your return type. This wildcard will accept any class that extends the Parent class

```java
public List<ExcelRecord<? extends Parent>> getExcelRecords() {
   //...
}
```

Feel free to check out the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more details

Comment: Hi @Paul, thanks for the reply. But in my case, the returned value is going to use in a legacy method, that can't change. If I change the returned type accordingly, I have to change all the other places as well.  My problem is why they don't allow to past child type generic to parent generic?

Comment: @PubuduMaheshMeththananda [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/6395627)

Comment: If you change the method the way Paul is mentioning, you don't need to change anything anywhere since the method will return exactly the same

Comment: `List<Foo<? extends Bar>> foo1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Foo<Bar>> foo2 = foo1;` - @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo such code-sample would not compile. If the method would be reimplemented in such a way that it would return `List<ExcelRecord<? extends Parent>>`, all the places in the code where this method is used would require to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making use of upper-bounded wild-card `? extends` there's a way to leave the return type of the method intact `List<ExcelRecord<Parent>>`.

And as you've specified in the question, it's a mandatory requirement.

> The returned value of this method is going to use in the legacy method which **can't be altered** accordingly.

How would it work?

Suppose we have the following dummy `ExcelRecord`

```
public class ExcelRecord<T> {
    private T item;

    public ExcelRecord(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

If the list was declared like that:

```
List<ExcelRecord<Parent>> records = new ArrayList<>();
```

We would be able to add only objects of type `ExcelRecord<Parent>` (or subtypes of `ExcelRecord` having generic type `Parent`, let's say `SubExcelRecord<Parent>`).

But **note** that `ExcelRecord<Parent>` itself can have property `item` of type parent `Parent` or its subtype, i.e. we can store `ChildOne` or `ChildTwo` in it. And the code would compile and work perfectly fine.

Here's a complete example:

```
public List<ExcelRecord<Parent>> getExcelRecords(){
    
    List<ExcelRecord<Parent>> records = new ArrayList<>();

    ExcelRecord<Parent> record1 = new ExcelRecord<>(new ChildOne()); // compiles fine
    records.add(record1);
    
    records.add(new ExcelRecord<>(new ChildTwo())); // fine as well 
    
    return records;
}
```

[Leaving and breathing Online Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xne)

Both of the lines below would compile successfully owing to Java 8 [target types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types).

```
// assignment context
ExcelRecord<Parent> record1 = new ExcelRecord<>(new ChildOne());

// method invocation context
records.add(new ExcelRecord<>(new ChildTwo()));
```

In both cases, `new ExcelRecord<>()` is a so called *poly-expression*, i.e. its type would depend on the context in which it appears. In the first case, the compiler would infer the type from the *assignment context*, in the second from the *invocation context*.

**Note** that if you would do something like that in your code, it would **not** compile. Your records should be of type `Parent`.

```
ExcelRecord<ChildOne> record1 = new ExcelRecord<>(new ChildOne());
records.add(record1); // would raise a complition error
```

Answer (score -1):

There're two ways to resolve, either remove **abstract** from Parent, or make Parent as interface, I recommend first one.